# How to use Pycharm with Virtual Environment / Django?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

Good afternoon everyone, I recently finished working with pygame and now I'm starting to learn Django because I've always wanted to make my own website.

Everyone who teaches Django tells their viewers they need a "virtual environment". I spent a whole day understanding what it is and how to create one, activate it, deactivate, install packages, pip freeze, etc etc etc.... I understood that part atleast the basics.

I'm going to be using Pythons built in "venv" and not "virtualenv", "pipenv" or any other virtual environment tool.

From what I learned about virtual environments, they recommend NOT to place stuff inside the virtual environment. Ok that I got...

I've been using Pycahrm as my IDE and has helped me a lot to learn programming.

My main question is:

Will the way I use Pycharm change NOW that I'm getting into Django and virtual environments?

With pygame or tkinter I just opened a new project (example: "robot_game") in Pycharm, a new directory was created with the name of "robot_game" and inside that folder another folder called "venv" was created. All my images, sounds and .py files where inside "robot_game", not inside "venv" folder. That was my normal rutine.

...but I remember when I first installed Pycharm, I made some settings changes related to "interpreters" and which one to use etc. Not sure if thats related to "virtual environments" and now that I'm starting with Django, should I start to make some changes or how does that REALLY works when using Python/Django/Pycharm/virtual environments?

I have python version 3.8.3

I'm a noob with python, started 4 months ago, any advice, analogy would help. Thank you for reading.

Comment: What you've been doing is just fine for django projects. You can have your venv where you want it. I put them in the root of the project which is the pycharm default, keeps things simple.

Comment: in pycharm there is an option to make django projects where pycharm itself makes an virtalenv for u. Does watching [dis](https://youtu.be/4AOv6Jm73Ug?list=PLhTjy8cBISEpXc-yjjSW90NgNyPYe7c9_&t=362) video from 6:00 to 7:00 help you?

Comment: When I open pycharm and select "new project", it doesnt give me the left column of framework options like in the video you shared. I have not "pip install Django" or created a virtual environment with "python -m venv my_project"...I'm confused now with pycharm and creating a virtual environment in the command line....